# Theorem 11 on pg. 82 proof elaboration (Royden $ 4^{th}$ edition).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral

The theorem and its proof and proposition 9 that is mentioned in the proof are given below:

> [image]
>   [image]

**My question is:**

I do not understand the last part in the last sentence of the proof "by proposition 9, the integral of a nonnegative function over a set of measure zero is zero", I do not understand how proposition 9 leads to this understanding, could anyone explains this for me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E$ has measure $0$ the any measurable function is $0$ almost everywhere on $E$. Because the statement $f(x)=0$ if $ x\in E$ and $x \notin E$ is vacuously true.